# First tab panel does not show data in grid (IE 9)

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2, extjs5

I have a tab panel and every tab has grid in it, but after loading, data in first tab is missing but it displays fine in 2nd tab , this is working in all the browsers in Extjs 4.2 but it is not working in Extjs 5.0 with IE. ( working fine in chrome ) thee is no errors on console. I am getting crazy with this issue. may be it is a bug in Extjs 5. Thanks in advance.

```
//main panel class

Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyView', {
  extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
  alias : 'widget.myView',
  id : 'myView',
  autoScroll : true,
  activeTab: 0,
  height: 600,

  layout: {
    type: 'column'
  },

  requires : [ 
    'MyView.view.FirstTab',
    'MyView.view.SecondTab'    
  ],

  initComponent : function() {

    this.items = [
      {  
       xtype: 'panel', 
       id: 'fTab',
       autoScroll: true, 
       items: [ { xtype: 'firstTab' }] 
      },
      {  
        xtype: 'panel', 
        id: 'sTab',
        autoScroll: true,
        items: [ { xtype: 'secondTab' } ] 
      }
  ];

    this.callParent(arguments);
  }
});

     //controller 

         var isActivieTabSet = false;

         // if store1 has data show the first tab
         if(store1Count > 0) {
            var tab0 = myView.down('#fTab');
            tab0.tab.show();
            if (!isActivieTabSet) {
              searchSummaryView.setActiveTab(tab0);
              isActivieTabSet = true;
            }          

          } else {
            myView.down('#fTab').tab.hide();
          }

          //check if store2 has data
          if(store2Count > 0) {
            var tab1 = myView.down('#sTab');
            tab1.tab.show();
            if (!isActivieTabSet) {
              myView.setActiveTab(tab1);
              isActivieTabSet = true;
            }
          } else {
            myView.down('#sTab').tab.hide();
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Grid is inside the panel and this panel is inside the main tabpanel. if i removed the panel over the Gris then it works fine.

//this does not works (does not show data in first tab)

```
      {  
       xtype: 'panel', 
       id: 'fTab',
       autoScroll: true, 
       items: [ { xtype: 'firstTab' }] 
      },
//this works 
      {  
       xtype: 'firstTab' 
      }
```

I guess this is a bug in Extjs 5.0, same code works in Extjs 4.2 and also in Chrome.

OK, i found the solution, I have to add this on the grid.

```
bufferedRenderer: false,
```

In Extjs 5 it is true by default and it is not behaving right in IE when the Grid is inside a Panel with pagination. after this everything works great :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I see these issues with your code:

1. you should not set a layout on tab panel. Tab panel uses card layout internally, most likely it ignores any passed layout but if you set it it may be confusing for developers
2. you set ids on components - they are unique in the code you posted but it may not be true for the whole application. The general rule is not to manually set ids - you don't need them.
3. you overnest - you don't need to wrap 'firstTab' in 'fTab'. We always try to use the most shallow containment chain possible.
4. hiding tabs is very unusual. I'm not saying that it wouldn't work but if you need to hide a tab then you can use card layout with some simple switching logic. Tab panel is de-facto a card layout with tab "buttons" to switch the active card.

Otherwise the code does not give a clue why it should misbehave. I would suggest a) fix the above and, if it does not help b) prepare a showcase at https://fiddle.sencha.com so that I can run it and find the real culprit.

Comment: any idea??, i tried in Extjs 5.0.0.970. same issue in IE9.

Comment: Two remaining issues, one can be related to the problem: you still overnest. Grid **is** a panel, do **not** wrap it in another panel. The second issue, unrelated is that you fire event on application - you shouldn't fire events on another instance, only this.fireEvent().

Comment: Good tips , thanks!! but we need to put a panel otherwise pagingtoolbar shows all the way on the botton & grid is on the top of the page (Card layout). anyway i find the solution by adding bufferedRenderer: false, in the Grid. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!!

1) Right , No need to specify the Layout on tab panel. I took this out

2) Right, it is a good practice to not add the Ids but we are nesting these components and show/hide by using these ids.

3) Right, that was the first thing that came to my mind, take out the wrapper panel from the grid and it works fine and show up the data but with this we have two issues.

a) In the Grid we are using 'pagingtoolbar' and shows at the botton (same in the whole application)

```
    this.dockedItems = [ { xtype: 'pagingtoolbar', store: this.store, displayInfo: true,  
 dock: 'bottom' } ];
```

We are using the CARD layout and when we take out the panel this always shows at the botton even though the grid has only 5 records and It looks very weird and we don't want to put this on top (dock: 'top' )

b) Other issue iis sometime Column Header and data are not aligned

```
 {header: 'Number', dataIndex: 'number', flex: 1 }
```

if i take out the flex:1 then all the columns get too narrow and half of the vertical space on the right is empty.

4) We have this use case that if grid does not have any data then don't show the tab. so we have to manually show/hide the tab.

Let me combine these classes & upload them (but it may time because I have to take out only the necessary objects :( ).

Thanks you again for your help!!